# как в regex работать с вложенностями?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

есть такой пример:

[image: мой regex:]

Но здесь вложенность мешает корректно считать обертку - он захватывает первую попавшуюся закрывающую фигурную скобку, а должен, в данном примере, брать вторую. Если будет еще одна вложенность - третью и т.д.

Есть ли возможность это реализовать?
Или нужно ручками искать правильную скобочную последовательность?

Вот сам regex: https://regex101.com/r/XA2SYl/1

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь так разобрать? Не всё нужно разбирать регулярками, есть форматы, которым разбор регулярками прямо противопоказан.

Comment: _Регулярные_ выражения предназначены для разбора _регулярных_ грамматик. Скобочная последовательность - _нерегулярная_. / Многие современные движки регулярок на самом деле умеют парсить нерегулярные грамматики (хотя название осталось regex). Уточните, какой именно движок используете. В .NET это зовётся [Balancing groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing-group-definitions). Вот [ещё](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html). / Но использовать их реально сложно. Вероятно, лучше написать конечный автомат.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Регулярные выражения не поддерживают рекурсивные или вложенные шаблоны.Или писать свой парсер или с помощью библиотеки [JSONPath](https://jsonpath.com/)